# But it is not an Enclave

Tags: riddle, wordplay, no-computers

> What country (sovereign) lies entirely within (inside) another country,
>
> But
>
> It is not an Enclave?

Two possible solutions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a word it could be

> Oman which is written inside Romania, but is not a geographical enclave.

Comment: One more @ Tom  There is one more

Comment: rot13[Avtre/Avtrevn]?

Comment: It is not the classic "within" another country in the spirit that was intended @jafe. Oman and Mali do I think

Answer (score 17):

Following on from Tom's answer, the second one is

> Mali which is in Somalia

Answer (score 8):

Could be

> **Monaco**, which on land is bordered by France from all sides and whose maritime borders are completely surrounded by French territorial waters. It doesn't count as an enclave because it's on the coast.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but if we’re counting semi-enclaves then Brunei would be as correct as your answer...

Comment: @El-Guest True... hmm...

Comment: @El-Guest and Gambia

Comment: Territorial waters count when considering a country as an enclave

Answer (score 8):

It could be

> India

since that lies entirely within

> (**in**s**id**e) **a**nother country

I presume there's others by that logic

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> Singapore?

This is because

> It’s a city state surrounded by Indonesia, but it’s not an enclave?

Answer (score 5):

Based on existing answers, it's:

> Russia, which is inside Belo*russia*

or, if you prefer

> in Belorussian, Русь inside Бела*русь* (using slightly glorious, less standard country name).

Alternately and more geographically,

> Munich in Italian is Monaco, and it lies completely within Germany, but Monaco is also a sovereign country. And it's not an enclave, it's a homonym.

Answer (score 3):

Entirely inside

> romania - oman 
>  somalia - mali

Somekind of inside

> dominican republic - dominica  
>  equatorial guinea - guinea  
>  guinea-bissau - guinea  
>  nigeria - niger  
>  papua new guinea - guinea  
>  south sudan - sudan

Answer (score -3):

> It can be vatican city. As it is completely surrounded by rome which is in Italy

Comment: Vatican City is an Enclave